# arrays and foreach

Tags: php

Any idea why this wont print the errors?

```
// Validate the email
if (preg_match($regex, $email))  
        $errors[] = "Invalid email address";

    // ... and the password
    if (strlen($password) < 4)
        $errors[] = "Password is too short";

    // No errors?   
    if (empty($errors))
    {
        // insert into db

    }

// If there were any errors, show them
if (!empty($errors))
{
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($errors as $error)
    echo '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
}
```

Comment: Could you please be less careless with your indentation? It'll make any code maintainer probably hate you. I know I'm cringing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are overwriting the array before output.

```
 $errors = array();  // Creates an empty array
 foreach ($errors as $error)  // Won't do anything
```

remove `$errors = array()` and it should work.

It would be cleaner by the way to initialize `$errors = array()` in the very beginning of the script, and then check for `count($errors) > 0` instead of `empty`:

```
// No errors?   
if (count($errors) == 0)
{
 // insert into db

}

// If there were any errors, show them
else
{
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($errors as $error)
    echo '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
}
```

that way, you will avoid notices about `$error` not being set.

Comment: Why not `empty`? It returns `true` for an empty array.

Comment: @Felix you're right, I didn't think of that. `empty` will work just as well.

Answer (score 3):

...because you're emptying the array just before trying to display its contents, see below

```
// If there were any errors, show them
if (!empty($errors))
{
    $errors = array();              // This line is emptying the array!
    foreach ($errors as $error)
    echo '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this line wipes the array:

```
$errors = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using this portion of code :

```
if (!empty($errors))
{
    $errors = array();    // Here, you are making the $errors array empty !
    foreach ($errors as $error)
    echo '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
}
```

Basically : you are emptying the array before trying to iterate over it with `foreach` -- so `foreach` will not loop at all, as you are giving it an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're overwriting the value of `$errors` in the first line if the last `if` statement.